# Custom order by in woocommerce filters the products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a website with 100 pages of products, which I want to sort by a meta value I have that not all products will have. So I made my custom ordering by overriding the default woocommerce one with `woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args` ([link](http://hookr.io/filters/woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args/)) like this:

```
function custom_order($args) {
   $args ['orderby'] = 'meta_value none';
   $args ['order'] = 'desc';
   $args ['meta_key'] = 'custom_something';
   return $args;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_order');
```

But since most products dont actually have that value, it wont sort on that. So I end up with only 2 pages after this filter has been added. Now I have thought about maybe ordering it 2 ways. So first by `custom_something` and then by some value that all products have like for example `price` or something, but that doesn't necessarily seem like the best idea and I also couldnt figure out how to do that.

I just want the products that have this value filled in, to be ordered by the above and then just show all the other products. Doesn't matter in what order the other products are. But the result now is that it only shows the products that have the value. It filters instead of ordering basically. How would I be able to accomplish this? I've seen this: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters but I can't really figure out how to apply this to my ordering.

**EDIT:**
 I've tried the answer from @johannes and when I `var_dump($args);` I get:

```
array(3) { 
["orderby"]=> string(15) "meta_value none"
["order"]=> string(4) "desc" 
["meta_key"]=> string(16) "custom_something"
}
```

I cant figure out why this wont work.

Comment: Don't you need to return the `$args` array after modifying it or am I wrong? Furthermore, the parameter(s) of your function is/are missing in your code.

Comment: @Johannes You're right, I just wanted to include the code that was necessary to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a fallback ordering field if your custom one is not present as written in the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters):

```
function custom_order($args) {
   $args['orderby'] = 'meta_value none';
   $args['order'] = 'desc';
   $args['meta_key'] = 'custom_something';
   return $args;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_get_catalog_ordering_args', 'custom_order');
```

I didn't had the chance to test it yet but this should advise WooCommerce to first order by the `meta_value` and then, if this value does not exist for a product, order by `none`.

Comment: This did not change the result for me. I copied your code. Are you sure nothing is missing?

Comment: I'm sorry, I've tested several possible solutions (e.g. `meta_query`) but none of them showed the desired result.